# How to list all tagged files in ranger

Tags: ranger

I have a nested directory with tagged files across the subdirectories. Is there any way to list all marked files in this nested hierarchy?

Answer (score 2):

You can run

```
ranger --list-tagged-files='*'
```

to list all files tagged with `*` (replace `*` if you used another tag).

So either use a special tag for your hierarchy or filter the output to the base directory.